# How in azure account increase number request limit on read when 429 error

Tags: azure-resource-manager

when i send more than 60 requests on site, i get 429 error

X-RateLimit-Limit
60
X-RateLimit-Remaining
59
11:28 AM
x-ratelimit-limit
60
x-ratelimit-remaining
0
x-ratelimit-reset
1594787767
429

Too Many Requests

---

there php service app, apache server

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is to not call the API so quickly.  You are being throttled because you are calling too frequently.

The longer answer is, it depends.  What API are you calling?  Every service in Azure has different rate limits for different activities.  I am not aware of one that throttles at a limit of 60, but if you can provide more details then we can provide more info.  You can also check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits for all of the documented limits and see if you are hitting a hard limit or a soft limit.

- If it is a soft limit, then you can usually open a support incident and have the limit raised (there are some limitations such as capacity, scenario, etc).
- If it is a hard limit then you will need to adjust your calling pattern.
- If it is a rate limit on one of your own resources (ie. calling a storage account), then you can possibly resize your resource to a more expensive SKU to increase those limits.